# OO design: Using Linq2Sql in Front-end pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

Would it be a terrible if I were to use Linq2Sql in my front end pages (ie: aspx and ascx pages). It would save me huge amounts of time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using LINQ to SQL"? If your .aspx page gets a collection of L2S entities and just displays them, it's perfectly fine. Simple queries are likely fine too. Something more complicated depends on what exactly it is. More details, please.

Comment: It's simple like populating a dropdown list with items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to match the amount of effort put into a project with the amount of maintenance  and the length of life of the project.  Quick and dirty hacks are perfectly suited for short-lived or never touched projects; but if you find yourself maintaining a mess then you'll see that your initial productivity boost resulted in a large long-term cost.

Comment: I'm a little biased when I say this but i like your answer the best. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. At least, assuming these pages will last long enough to ever need modification. And they will, even if they're "just a quick hack"...or maybe thats *especially* if they're "just a quick hack".

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it sounds so simple now. But quick hacks almost always come back to bite you in the bum. You'd be better off if you have a presentation model that's used on the front end. That way your visual elements only know what the need to know, no extra database related stuff, no additional mappings, no accidental loading extra data.

Yes, it will be a bit of additional work but long term it will most certainly pay off.